# Drag an image when image size is biger then min criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

i am new in jquery .
I want drag image when my image is bigger then div size.
example:when we upload cover image if my image size is bigger then cover image div then they ask us to set image which part we want to show.
I want this type of functionality
  my code is:

```
    <div class="main">
           <img class="absolute" src="http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
```

css:

```
.main{
    width:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}

img.absolute{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

hope you understand my question

Comment: can u provide fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jaap/wjw83/5/

Comment: its not my fiddle . I refer this fiddle for overflow

Comment: so u want to crop your image if your image size is greater rit.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jcrop , which is a jQuery plugin specifically for coping and manipulating images.

You can find the library [here](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php)

For drag and drop there is also another great plugin i.e. jWindowCrop.

You can find it [here.](https://github.com/tybro0103/jWindowCrop)

Comment: I knew the jcrop concept but my task is drag an crop .as like in facebook cover image

Comment: @sonalgoyal : I have updated the answer, have a look

Comment: @sonalgoyal: the files are ~8 kb in size, so I don't think that will be much of a performance issue, and I have also updated the link to GitHub you can have a look.